# How can I capture a html div with all encountered value of input controls in string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div like this

```
<div id="content">
  <div>
   <input type="text"/>
   </div>
 </div>
```

and some one enter a text `abc` in textbox and click save then need a code which return `var a='<div><input type="text" value="abc"/></div></div>'`

`$("#content").html()` not working for me.

Comment: i know i can get it by .val();

Comment: but i need whole div which is in div#content as string 
means my output will be like 
'<div><input type="text" value="abc" /></div>'

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED:** Try setting the input attribute.I Have updated this for multiple input fields.

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
 $('button').on('click',function(){
 $('input').each(function(){//looping each input field here
  $(this).attr('value', $(this).val());//you need to set the attribute value to get in html
            
 });

 console.log($("#content").html());
});
});
```

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
  <div>
   <input type="text"/>
 <input type="text"/>
   <input type="text"/>
   </div>
 </div>
<button >click</button>
```

Comment: thanks, its correct for current context but suppose i have 100 textboxes and radio buttons then it is a tough task to do same.